# Drawer Animation Error :'Animation<FractionalOffset>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animation<Offset>'

Tags: android, flutter

As I'm implementing Animation for New Screen with `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/abc');`,
I got an error as below :

> error: The argument type 'Animation' can't be
>   assigned to the parameter type 'Animation'.
>   (argument_type_not_assignable at [mhtportal_notifications]
>   lib\main.dart:194)

with Code block (Class) as below :

```
class FromRightToLeft<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  FromRightToLeft({ WidgetBuilder builder, RouteSettings settings })
      : super(builder: builder, settings: settings);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(
      BuildContext context,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      Widget child) {

    if (settings.isInitialRoute)
      return child;

    return new SlideTransition(
      child: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              new BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black26,
                blurRadius: 25.0,
              )
            ]
        ),
        child: child,
      ),
      position: new FractionalOffsetTween(
        begin: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
        end: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
      )
          .animate(
          new CurvedAnimation(
            parent: animation,
            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
          )
      ),
    );
  }
  @override Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 400);
}
```

Code Source : [GitHub](https://github.com/felipecarvalho/flutterstarter/blob/master/lib/main.dart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're using a `FractionalOffset` while the animation expects an `Offset`.

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
return new SlideTransition(
  child: new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      boxShadow: [
        new BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black26,
          blurRadius: 25.0,
        )
      ]
    ),
    child: child,
  ),
  position: new Tween(
    begin: const Offset(1.0, 0.0),
    end: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
  )
  .animate(
    new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: animation,
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    )
  ),
);
```

There's a [flutter bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13812) about this (since closed) with some more information - in particular [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-dev/fmr-C9xK5t4) on the flutter forum that provides a bit more information about this change and why they did it.